# Do users have veto power over suggested edits to their post?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

If reviewers make a decision to accept/reject a suggested edit, does the original poster have a way to overturn their decision?

I've made a few edits that were rejected by reviewers. I thought they were improvements to the site that would help others in the future, but it seems they did not fit within SO policy.

It is my impression that the OP is in the best position to decide whether or not an edit is an improvement because rather than being responsible for impartially interpreting a policy, they need only to decide whether the change improves their question or answer.

So, I would like to know if the OP is notified of edits and given an opportunity to accept or reject them, should they have an interest in doing so.

Comment: Yes, owners are notified and have veto rights. But only when the suggested edit is still actively being reviewed.

Comment: From the duplicate "The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post."

Comment: @MartijnPieters why can they only veto during the review? My last edit was rejected in less than an hour: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3087108 Very few OPs  would be active enough to be able to intervene during such a short time window.

Comment: @Nathan: The OP is still notified. They can look at your suggestion and edit the post themselves if they feel it was a change worth making.

Comment: "Very few OPs would be active enough to be able to intervene during such a short time window" ....yes, I definitely don't usually have sub 5 minute response times, yes, yes

Comment: "It is my impression that the OP is in the best position to decide whether or not an edit is an improvement" Considering the mangling I see done to English in far too many posts, I disagree with this statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OPs do not have the ability to veto an edit once it has been accepted, but they do have the ability to rollback. As such, if an edit fundamentally changes the nature of what was written, they can rollback the revision.

The downside, of course, is a reversion war - because a high rep user can rollback a rollback.

Comment: ...but then it would be expected that the higher rep user will have the common sense to take a step back and call in a moderator if he really believes the edit is necessary.

Comment: When the edit is still active (i.e. has not been accepted or rejected), the OP does have a veto ability.

Comment: "*If reviewers **make a decision** to accept/reject a suggested edit, does the original poster have a way to **overturn** their decision?*" <- The OP makes it sound like the edit has already taken effect, not that voting is still in progress. I think Affable Geek's interpretation is correct.

Comment: Hmm, yep. True in that case @Cybȫʁgϟ37. (Minor edit to the answer to clarify. Roll back if you don't agree with it ;) )